# How do I find the Euclidean distance between one point and all the points in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, distance

I want to find the Euclidean distance between one point (x1) and a list of points (y1), which contains a lot of coordinates

```
x1 = killer[[2]]
```

> {6.05102, 5.87667}

```
y1 = victim[[2 ;;]]
```

> {{1.40687, 4.92494}, {0.419206, 1.70406}, {6.29657,0.577941}, {4.12022, 4.94952},
>   {2.04784, 5.94545}, {1.29192,1.43152}, {3.26737, 1.90134}, {4.27274, 0.528028},
>   {2.79659,1.37788}, {5.43955, 1.81355}}

Is it possible for me to find the `EuclideanDistance` between x1 and y1, where it will show all results between x1 and each elements in y1.

Comment: Try `EuclideanDistance[x1,#]&/@y1`!

Comment: You need to read up on [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html).

Comment: Related: [Calculating the distance between the coordinates in a list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8272/131)

Comment: @PlatoManiac If efficiency is important, one can gain an order of magnitude speedup by using `Sqrt[Total[(x1 - #)^2]] & /@ y1` instead, due to auto-compilation (`EuclideanDistance` is not compilable). Slightly faster still can be a vectorized solution like  `Sqrt[Total[(Transpose[y1] - x1)^2]]`.

Comment: Also [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203910/select-points-within-a-circular-area-in-mathematica)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin how woud a solution based on `Norm[]` fare?

Comment: @YvesKlett Actually, I was surprised but it does pretty well when used in `Map` - about 1.5 times slower than `Sqrt[Total[(x1 - #)^2]] &` only (so, obviously, also auto-compiled). I seem to remember testing it before and results were worse.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin It is an important issue about speed you have raised here. But for a small example like this I thought compilation might be an Overkill and it did not at all occur in my mind! But thanks for pointing that out you inspire us towards perfection..;)

Comment: @OleksandrR. You are right. This explanation crossed my mind, but I was too lazy to test it :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is what you want to do. Let the first point's coordinate be stored as a list of list as follows:

```
x1 = {{6.05102, 5.87667}}
```

and the second set of coordinates

```
y1 = {{1.40687, 4.92494}, {0.419206, 1.70406}, {6.29657,0.577941}, {4.12022, 4.94952},
      {2.04784, 5.94545}, {1.29192,1.43152}, {3.26737, 1.90134}, {4.27274, 0.528028},
      {2.79659,1.37788}, {5.43955, 1.81355}}
```

Now to compute the Euclidean distances between `x1` and every element in `y1` use `Outer`, your best friend from now on.

```
Outer[EuclideanDistance, x1, y1, 1]//Flatten
```

This then gives you

```
{4.74067, 7.00914, 5.30442, 2.14187, 4.00377, 6.51217, 4.85304, 5.63651, 5.55252, 4.10887}.
```

Hope this helps. In fact, you can loop this through various x1's as follows.

```
Table[Outer[EuclideanDistance, {killer[[k]]}, y1, 1], {k, 1, n}]
```

Where n is the Length of the killer list. This is fast and compact code.

Comment: Just a suggestion: formatting code inline with text makes copy&pasting less convenient compared to separate code lines.

Comment: @Yves, sorry I'm new to StackExchange, I'll try to edit it.

Comment: You don't even need the `Table`. Just put the entire list of `x1` into `Outer`.

Comment: No worries whatsoever, welcome to the party!

Comment: @Jens, yes you're right. In this case you don't. But suppose you want to do further analysis of a large data set, like calculate the Max or Min of the distances from each of the x1's, then the table definitely comes in handy for Memory conservation. Otherwise Mathematica will store all of those unnecessary data in memory, because Outer will have to finish before you can Map "Min" or "Max" to the entire List.

Answer (score 13):

I would use [`DistanceMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceMatrix) for this. Here is a comparison of [`DistanceMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceMatrix) with the other answers:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[1, {10^7, 2}];

r1 = First @ DistanceMatrix[{{1., 1.}}, data]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = distance[{1,1}, data]; //AbsoluteTiming (* Mahdi *)
r3 = Outer[EuclideanDistance, {{1., 1.}}, data, 1] //Flatten; //AbsoluteTiming (* RunnyKine *)

r1 == r2 == r3
```

> {0.384095, Null}
>
> {0.88146, Null}
>
> {9.64241, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 9):

I understand that this question already has an accepted answer, but couldn't resist posting my answer. This answer is mainly useful if you have a very large dataset. I define the following function using `Compile` function in Mathematica.

```
distance = Compile[{{n, _Real, 1}, {z, _Real, 2}},
Sqrt[Total[(# - n)^2]] & /@ z, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
];
```

Then we map the function over a two dimensional set with 10000000 (=$10^7$) points.

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000000, 2}];
```

The result is:

```
new[{0, 0}, data] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.609684 s *)
```

which is 10 times faster compared to the accepted answer:

```
Outer[EuclideanDistance, {{0, 0}}, data, 1] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 5.927118 s *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a vectorized solution:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[1, {10^7, 2}];
pt = {1., 1.};

res2 = Sqrt@Total[(Transpose[data] - pt)^2]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.472308, Null} *)
```

Compare to Carl's `DistanceMatrix`, Mahdi's compiled version and jkuczm's compiled version:

```
res1 = First@DistanceMatrix[{pt}, data]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.399328, Null} *)

res3 = distance[{1, 1}, data]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.958243, Null} *)

res5 = distanceLib[{1,1 }, data]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.065559, Null} *)

res1 == res2 == res3
(* True *)
```

The lesson is that while built-in functions are usually the best (or at least have the highest potential for running fast), vectorization is usually the next best thing, and often beats an auto-parallelized compiled implementation.

I suspect that this is because vectorization can make use of not only parallelization, but also [SIMD instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD).

Finally, vector arithmetic probably relies on the [MKL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library), a highly optimized library that auto-generated C code just can't compete with.

---

As an experiment, we can also compare the performance of hand-written C++ code.  While naive C++ code won't be parallelized, we have the advantage that we know in advance that we are going to be working with 2D points, so we can specialize the code for that case.

Using [LTemplate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96128/12) (to save time),

```
Needs["LTemplate`"]
SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];

tem = LClass["Dist",
   {LFun["dist", {{Real, 1, "Constant"} (* point *), {Real, 2, "Constant"} (* point list *)}, {Real, 1}(* distance list *)]}
   ];

code = "
  #include <cmath>

  using namespace mma;

  struct Dist {
    RealTensorRef dist(RealTensorRef pt, RealMatrixRef ptlist) {
        massert(pt.size() == 2 && ptlist.cols() == 2);
        auto res = makeVector<double>(ptlist.rows());
        for (int i=0; i < res.size(); ++i)
            res[i] = std::hypot(ptlist(i,0) - pt[0], ptlist(i,1) - pt[1]);
        return res;
    }   
  };
  ";
Export["Dist.h", code, "String"];

CompileTemplate[tem]
LoadTemplate[tem]
obj = Make[Dist]

res4 = obj@"dist"[pt, data]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.05077, Null} *)

res1 == res4
(* True *)
```

That's a 7.5x speedup over the `DistanceMatrix` function with only a trivial amount of naïve C++ code.  I think this illustrates well the advantages of LTemplate. It makes LibraryLink development easy enough that I can write libraries like this in as little as 5 minutes.  Using plain LibraryLink, it would take several times longer, which is enough of a deterrent that I would not do this nearly as frequently as LTemplate allows me to.

*Update:* It's only marginally faster than jkuczm's `distanceLib`.

---

Since people using a slow system like the Raspberry Pi may be particularly interested in performance, here's a benchmark with $10^6$ points on a first-gen RPi / Raspbian Jessie / gcc 4.9.2 / Mathematica 11.0.1:

DistanceMatrix: 1.12 s; Vectorization: 1.44 s; Library function: 0.67 s.

The speedup is not as dramatic as it was on OS X / x86_64. I am not sure if gcc 6.3 in Raspbian Stretch would bring any improvements.

Comment: +1  Perhaps add link to your LTemplate (to save time searching for a package that saves time...)?

Comment: @bobthechemist I thought I had already added the link!  Thanks for pointing out that it was missing.

Comment: @bobthechemist Just added on RPi benchmark for you.

Comment: Thanks - I suspect there is only so much that can be done with the caps on RAM and a 32 bit OS.  Even small improvements are worth the effort, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

[Mahdi's compiled function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76648/14303) is not really using runtime `Listable` attribute, since it accepts rank 2 tensor as second argument.

To use runtime listability and `Parallelization` we need to define function accepting lower rank tensor:

```
distanceListable = Compile[{{x0, _Real, 1}, {x, _Real, 1}},
    Sqrt[
        Subtract[Compile`GetElement[x, 1], Compile`GetElement[x0, 1]]^2+
        Subtract[Compile`GetElement[x, 2], Compile`GetElement[x0, 2]]^2
    ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
    Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
];
```

If we accept rank 2 tensor and manually loop over it, we don't need runtime attributes, and can completely get rid of `CompiledFunction` overhead by directly using underlying `LibraryFunction` (`Last` element of `CompiledFunction`):

```
distanceLib = Last@Compile[{{x0, _Real, 1}, {x, _Real, 2}},
    Table[
        Sqrt[
            Subtract[Compile`GetElement[x, i, 1], Compile`GetElement[x0, 1]]^2+
            Subtract[Compile`GetElement[x, i, 2], Compile`GetElement[x0, 2]]^2
        ],
        {i, Length@x}
    ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];
```

On my machine [vectorized solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18929/how-do-i-find-the-euclidean-distance-between-one-point-and-all-the-points-in-a-l#comment57134_18929) has same speed as [`DistanceMatrix` solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159146/14303) but uses less memory, listable compiled function is about two times faster and uses least amount of memory, library function, extracted from compiled function with manual looping, is almost seven times faster.

```
SeedRandom@1;
x0 = {1., 1.} // Developer`ToPackedArray;
data = RandomReal[1, {10^7, 2}];

r1 = distance[x0, data]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.946,  240003488} *)
r2 = First@DistanceMatrix[{x0}, data]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.56,   490785120} *)
r3 = Sqrt@Total[Subtract[Transpose@data, x0]^2]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.56,   320001120} *)
r4 = distanceListable[x0, data]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.351,   80004264} *)
r5 = distanceLib[x0, data]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0815, 160000440} *)

r1 === r2 === r3 === r4 === r5
(* True *)
```

Comment: I just realized that I didn't use constant passing for my library function. Doing so gave a much larger speedup than I expected.  Maybe that could have something to do with why the library function extracted form the compiled function is so fast?  (But it doesn't make sense.)

Comment: I kind of wish you had benchmarked the LibraryLink version too, especially if you're on Windows :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs `distanceLib` does use  `"Constant"` argument passing. I thought that difference between `CompiledFunction` and extracted from it `LibraryFunction` comes from the fact that `CompiledFunction` is doing something with function result [which requires making copy of it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92178/14303).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, I just didn't phrase it very well.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm on Linux, `LTemplate` version is surprisingly slow on my computer: `0.230` s, only `2.4` times faster than `DistanceMatrix`. Maybe I have "weak" default compiler optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for trying!  What's your gcc version?

Comment: @Szabolcs 4.8.5

Comment: I do have gcc 4.8.5 too, though it's not my default (I use it for compatibility reasons). I think I solved the mystery.  If I replace `std::hypot` with my own implementation, such as `inline double hyp(double x, double y) { return std::sqrt(x*x+y*y); }`, then it will be much faster. I think that gcc doesn't have a well-optimized hypot, but clang does (I used clang on macOS for the benchmarks in my answer). If  specify `-march=native` too, the speed with Linux/gcc 4.8.5 finally almost matches what I get on macOS with clang (I'm running Linux in VirtualBox on the same CPU).

Comment: I think that the macOS compiler is more willing to make use of advanced CPU features than the Linux one, as Apple computers compatible with my OS *all* have a relatively modern CPU while Ubuntu might run on almost any CPU, even old ones. `-march=native` tells gcc to use all instructions that my CPU supports.  (But replacing `std::hypot` had a *much* bigger effect.)

Comment: Oh, and gcc 6.3 is no better at all than 4.8.5 ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, it's `std::hypot`s fault. After replacing it with `hyp` I get `0.0688` s, which is over 8 times faster than `DistanceMatrix`.