# Finding total distance between a point and all points in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I am looking for the total distance from each point in a list to all points in a another. Specifically from each point in `Asubopt` to every point in `A`.

```
ClearAll["Global'*"];
n = 5
A = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 2], {n, 2}]
dtotal[f_] := Total[Sqrt[Total[(Transpose[f] - {x, y})^2]]]
minA = FindMinimum[dtotal[A], {x}, {y}]
Asub = Subsets[A, {1, n}]
Asubdist = Map[dtotal, Subsets[A, {1, n}]]
Asubopt = {x, y} /. FindMinimum[#, {x}, {y}][[2]] & /@ Asubdist
Table[Outer[EuclideanDistance, {Asubopt[[i]]}, A, 1], {i, 1, n}]`
```

I read

- [How do I find the Euclidean distance between one point and all the points in a list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18929/how-do-i-find-the-euclidean-distance-between-one-point-and-all-the-points-in-a-l?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but the suggested `Table` does not seem to return the correct output.

Comment: There are a number of syntax errors in your code. The second line does not evaluated properly and the use of `FindMinimum` is incorrect as well. Please review your code for syntax errors first.

Comment: Try `DistanceMatrix[Asubopt, A]`

Comment: Thanks I added the space in the second line and DistanceMatrix[Asubopt,A] does contain the information I need but also computes all the distances to points in Asubopt as well.

Comment: I have used NMinimize as well.                                     
     ClearAll["Global'*"];
     n = 5
     A = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 2], {n, 2}]

     dtotal[f_] := Total[Sqrt[Total[(Transpose[f] - {x, y})^2]]]

     minA = NMinimize[dtotal[A], {x, y}]

     Asub = Subsets[A, {1, n}]

     Asubdist = Map[dtotal, Subsets[A, {1, n}]]

     Asubopt = {x, y} /. NMinimize[#, {x, y}][[2]] & /@ Asubdist

Comment: Thanks Carl Total[DistanceMatrix[Asubopt,A],{2}] was what I was looking for!

Comment: This is not *minimal* distance, but *total* distance. I'll change the question head appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments, the solution is

```
Total[DistanceMatrix[Asubopt,A],{2}]
```